# How to save image in to folder or directory in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have A image like this

```
imgScreenShot.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

instead of binding image to that imgScreenShot i have to save that in to either any folder in project or any directory please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to convert base64 image string to image.
Below is the code you can use to convert it to image :

```
    public static Image LoadImage(string base64string)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string); //Convert.FromBase64String("R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==");

        Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        return image;
    }
```

You can then save image as follows :

```
Image image = UtilityHelper.LoadImage(ch.Message);
string imgname = ch.MobileNo + "_" +        DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".jpg";
string filepath = Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~\\Images\\") + subPath + "\\" + imgname);
var image2 = new Bitmap(image);

image2.Save(filepath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```